# c# sql server backup percent read

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

sql command

```
BACKUP DATABASE [databasesample] TO  DISK = N'D:\kkk\test.bat' WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD , 
NAME = N'name test',  NOSKIP ,  
STATS = 5,  DESCRIPTION = N'test',  NOFORMAT
```

result

```
5 percent processed.
10 percent processed.
15 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
25 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
35 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
45 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
55 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
65 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
75 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
85 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
95 percent processed.
Processed 30960 pages for database 'databasesample', file 'sample_Data' on file 1.
100 percent processed.
```

I want to catch the percentage with C#. I think `BeginExecuteNonQuery()` function is done. but I do not know exactly how. Suggestions?

Comment: I think I have an answer but a little complicated here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server backup percent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763633/sql-server-backup-percent)

Comment: You just asked this and it was closed, why would you ask it again?

Comment: Not a 'possible' duplicate.  It's the exact same question asked a second time 8 minutes later by the same person.

Comment: I wonder something or not like the question I ask is closed. I wrote him again.

Comment: If your question is closed because it doesn't make sense, there really is no sense in posting it again with almost the exact same content. Instead, try to figure out *why* it was closed, and rectify that. Asking another question with more detail is OK. Posting the same question twice, is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides from using the SMO method as other have indicated, or from sneaking the `percent_complete` column of [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx), there is also another question asked here: how to I capture those `5 percent complete` messages in C#?

The percent complete is an informational message. All informational messages in C# can be captured from the [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event.

Comment: Can you give an example SqlConnection.InfoMessage user?

Comment: @Talat: In the link in my post there is a small paragraph that states "For more information and an example, see Connection Events (ADO.NET).". You click there and it takes you to a full example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w.aspx. Welcome to the Internet.

Comment: con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(con_InfoMessage); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: messages did not come one by one came to public

Comment: I found at the end of thumbs up, trying to super-
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ADOProgress.aspx
 thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [SMO tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724.aspx) which contain a [`Backup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx) class which sends a [`PercentCompleteNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.percentcompletenotification.aspx) via a [`PercentComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.percentcomplete.aspx) event.  I love the SMO tools - they're powerful and easy to use.

Comment: SMO will not use tools. because it gives a lot of bugs in the system, does not work correctly. SMO means of this tool can do the work, so I approached this work, but I think no one understands.

Comment: I mean no offense, Talat Eri, but if you intend to use an English-based website, you need better English.

Comment: SMO used it before, but I did not get the yield, the percentage representation of myself, so I'll need the appropriate C # code. okay?

Answer (score 0):

What shaunmartin said!

Last time I did this, I used code somewhat like this. YMMV.

```
  Server server = new Server(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection));

  // Create a backup device
  Backup backup = new Backup();
  backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
  backup.Database = database;
  backup.Incremental = false;
  backup.Initialize = true;

  BackupDeviceItem backupDeviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(backupPath, DeviceType.File);
  backup.Devices.Add(backupDeviceItem);

  backup.PercentCompleteNotification = 1;
  backup.Information += new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerMessageEventHandler(backup_Information);
  backup.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(backup_PercentComplete);
  backup.Complete += new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerMessageEventHandler(backup_Complete);

  backup.SqlBackupAsync(server);
```

Comment: SMO used it before. to work correctly on other computers, some percentage of fault to have fallen to do it myself, so I want to encode it myself. 'm explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as others have (now!) said, the [SMO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724.aspx) is very useful.  Here's a snippet from my backup application.  it's in VB, not C#, and it runs the backup synchronously, unlike the earlier example, but it works well.  We run it in a loop for all the 20-odd databases on our server.  Very reliable.

```
Dim bkp As Backup = New Backup()
With bkp

    .Devices.AddDevice(Me.currentBackupFileName, DeviceType.File)

    .Database = conn.DatabaseName
    .Action = BackupActionType.Database
    .Initialize = True
    .PercentCompleteNotification = 20
    AddHandler .PercentComplete, AddressOf HandleBackupProgress
    .SqlBackup(svr)

    Me.backupFiles.Add(Me.currentBackupFileName)

End With
```

The handler receives a `PercentCompleteEventArgs e`  as its argument, and you just pull the percentage complete out of it using `e.Percent`.

Comment: friends do not read what I typed the answers always the same answer under the ship.

Comment: SMO. net 4.0 fails to backup system. . net 3.5 is the system sometimes works, does not work on other computers, so I read parts of the C # code I need the sql result percentage.